# How is $A.in$ an inherited attributed in $2nd$ production in $(1) S \rightarrow A_1A_2\{ A_1.in := 1; A_2.in := 2 \}(2) A\rightarrow a\{print(A.in)\}$

Tags: compilers, parsers, attribute-grammars

Below is an excerpt from the Red Dragon book.

> $$(1) \quad S \rightarrow A_1 \quad A_2 \quad\{ A_1.in : = 1;\quad A_2.in : = 2 ;\}$$
> $$(2) \quad A  \rightarrow a \quad \{ print(A.in) \}$$
>
> We find that the inherited attribute $A.in$ in the second production is not defined when an attempt is made to print its value during a depth-first traversal of the parse tree for the input string $aa$.

Now the authors define inherited attributes as:
An inherited attribute is one whose value at a node in a parse tree is defined in terms of attributes at ***the parent and/or siblings of that node***.

But in the above excerpt, $A.in$ for the nodes $A$ of the parse is not defined in terms of attributes at the parent or siblings. But rather it is sort of based on itself.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Did not really study compilers, but own the book:) In my old copy I read "$b := f(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k)$ where $f$ is a function, and either [...] 2. $b$ is an inherited attribute of one of the grammar symbols on the right side of the production, and $c_1, c_2,\dots, c_k$ are attributes belonging to grammar symbols of the production." That means we may use any attribute in the production, so even of the variable itself. Also: a constant technically is a function of no variables, so would satisfy the definition anyhow.

Comment: @Hendrik, now that you point out, I can understand it roughly... The main problem was their previous definition of inherited attributes (which is more intuitive and logical) which said about dependence on attributes of `parent/siblings`. In $2$ they try to loosen the definition a bit... Very odd (without the mention that they are actually letting loose the definition). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the above excerpt, $A.in$ for the nodes $A$ of the parse is not defined in terms of attributes at the parent of siblings.

Yes, it is. The parent of $A\to a$ is $S \to A_1 A_2$. $S$ has two children, both of which are instances of $A$. And the rule for  $S \to A_1 A_2$ assigns values to the inherited attributes of both children.

That's precisely what an inherited attribute is. Inherited attributes (which are inherited from the parents in the parse tree) can be used in the synthesized rules for those non-terminals, which is what is happening in the rule for $A$.

Comment: I am facing a few difficulties, `S→A1A2 assigns values to the inherited attributes of both children` that is the problem I am having. Why do you say that the production assigns values to `inherited attributes` of both child. How do they become inherited? Is it so that that something like this is happening: `A.in:=f(S.attributes)` as per this `A.in` shall be `inherited` attribute, but here `f(S.attributes)` happens to be constant function. And in the last sentence, `... those non-terminals,...` which non-terminal? Current non-terminal under consideration? (contd..)

Comment: And yes as the text says, a procedure call like printing is a sort of dummy synthesized attribute operation, which is happening in the production `A→a`, which is happening as you said. And sorry being unable to understand few parts... I am just learning, so I haven't developed the intuition :(

Comment: If you assign an attribute of the left!-hand side symbol, it's synthesized. If you assign to an attribute of a symbol on the right hand side it is inherited. And yes, constant functions are functions.

Comment: Inherited attributes of an instance of some symbol can be used in the computation of synthesized attributes of that same object.

Comment: `If you assign an attribute of the left!-hand side symbol, it's synthesized. If you assign to an attribute of a symbol on the right hand side it is inherited.` Aah, very very clear point. Thank you... :)